# Fragment and factory method

Tags: android

What is the aim of using a Factory to construct our fragments?
Android Studio provides some boilerplate code generation, and provides the factory method when creating a fragment.

So what is the purpose of that? What is the gain?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using static factory method is not just for the fragment, I use it to create intent, adapter and other classes as well.  By this approach you simply have the control of the object creation.

One of the good advantage is you simply increase the cohesion by encapsulating bundle keys.

```
class FragmentFoo extends Fragment{
}
```

When you want to send a bundle to this fragment from outside

```
// Activity Foo
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("name","Foo");
Fragment fragment = new FragmentFoo();
fragment.setArgs(bundle);
```

To extract this name, you need to use "name" key in fragment as well, if you use it as hardcoded, you may have some errors,typos. So you can use a constant in order to make sure you don't make typo. But in this case you need to put it somewhere both can see it. Some creates another class in order to keep all contants which is very ugly and hard to maintain, some puts the keys in the fragment and make it public and use it everywhere,

by static factory method, you can simply keep everything in fragment and no need to expose. Whoever needs to use this fragment will have a clear idea what it requires and also will not need to know what keys are. Just send the required params will be enough for them.

```
class FragmentFoo extends Fragment{

   private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";

   private String name;

   public static Fragment newInstance(String name){
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
       bundle.putString(KEY_NAME, "name");
       Fragment fragment = new FragmentFoo();
       fragment.setArgs(bundle);

       return fragment;
   }
}
```

Comment: bundle.putString(KEY_NAME, "name");
In this line of the newInstance() method, should it be the string "name" or the argument name? If it's "name", where is the parameter used here then?

Answer (score 3):

Static factory methods allow us to initialize and setup a new Fragment without having to call its constructor and additional setter methods. Providing static factory methods for your fragments is good practice because it encapsulates and abstracts the steps required to setup the object from the client.

http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/using-newinstance-to-instantiate.html

Comment: I guess that makes sense. If you want to create the Fragment with the same parameters rather than default, but cannot use parameterized constructors because of how Fragments work (Bundles preserve data over configuration change).

Answer (score 1):

A Fragment must have a constructor with no arguments. That's because Android will call the default constructor to recreate the fragment. If you're not passing in arguments, then you should not need either a constructor or a static factory method (AKA, virtual constructor).

Answer (score 1):

If you create a fragment via template then remove all code in fragment then add constructor and hypothetical arguments which you want to pass to fragment

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    public BlankFragment(int arg)
    {

    }
}
```

you will get this pop up message

> Avoid non-default constructors in fragments...
>
> Every fragment must have an empty constructor, so it can be instantiated when restoring its activity's state. It is strongly recommended that subclasses do not have other constructors with parameters, since these constructors will not be called when the fragment is re-instantiated; instead, arguments can be supplied by the caller with setArguments(Bundle) and later retrieved by the Fragment with getArguments().

The Android system instantiates fragments with the no args constructor, which means you need to add a second constructor with no args for the Android System to re-initialize the fragment on state change events like when phone goes into landscape mode and fragment is destroyed then recreated by Android (not your host activity)

```
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    public BlankFragment()
    {

    }

    public BlankFragment(int arg)
    {

    }
}
```

Now if you tilt your phone and go to land scape mode, Android will re-init the fragment from the empty constructor, but you won't get your arguments passed to it.

You can still get the bundle on a state change, but you now have two constructors when you could have a single static factory method.